# How To Change Default View In MVC 4 Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

By default, MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2017 sets `_Layout.cshtml` as the default layout for all pages. I believe it's doing this in `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

(Index is set as the home page)

[image]

I'm still not sure how Index is getting `_Layout.cshtml`. But what if I'm trying to set a different view - a login page - as the home page, like this?

[image]

Also I'm trying to get rid of the Reports, Accounts, Settings, and Logout `<li>'s` in the header so that the page matches the design above. I'll also need a container with a form inside of it.

I've tried creating a `_Login` view inside of `/Home` and `/Shared` and changed `"Index"` to `"Login"` in `App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

[image]

But that's giving me an error:

[image]

How can I create a view and set that view as the default view for this MVC 4 Web App? Thanks

Comment: The default Layout is set in *Views/_ViewStart.cshtml* `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"`.

Comment: Oh okay. I do actually have `_Login.cshtml` set in `_ViewStart.cshtml` though. I have `_Login.cshtml` instead of `_Layout.cshtml` and I'm still getting the above error message. My `_ViewStart.cshtml` looks like this: 

`@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Login.cshtml";
}`

Comment: Is it that you need different layouts for different views?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I'll need 4 different pages, some pages will need more than 1 view. I.e. here's what I'm trying to create: http://imgur.com/a/icVUz

Comment: The error you are getting seems to be because the login action is not found in the home controller.

Comment: You typically can do a lot with one Layout. But you can always override the default `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutLogin.cshtml"` in individual view pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in the *defaults* parameters as `action` is the name of the controller's method, not view, so you should create a method named `Login` in the `Home` controller and create the associated View for that (In the `Login` method right click and choose Add View). Then it will act as the default home page.

```
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

So your `Home` controller looks like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
    //other codes   
 }
```

Also if you do not want the default layout to be used in the Login page you may add this at top of the Login page

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
```

Comment: This did change the body for the default home page. So how would I get rid of the (right side) links in the header? http://i.imgur.com/zy070R2.png I.e. how do I change the header for the new default view?

Comment: They are in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. look at this part `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">`

Comment: Yes. That's because `_Layout.cshtml` is the default layout. If you don't like it you can change it as others said in their comments and also I'm going to update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The error you see doesn't seem to be because of the layout page.

This error is because the Login Action is missing in the Home controller.

You see, The defaults specified are `Controlller="Home", Action="Login"`.
i.e. The compiler looks for the Login action in the Home controller. and when it doesn't find, it throws this error!

you could get rid of it by adding the login action like:

```
public ActionResult Login(string Uname, string Password)
{
    return View();
}
```

in the home controller! That's for the error in the question.

Here is the solution for your problem. 
You could add a different layout for each of your views by adding a razor code like below, to specify the layout for the view.

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
                  //This is the path to the layout. You could change this to your custom layout's path.
}
```

Hope this helps!